# How to safely process messages in parallel?

Tags: c#, multithreading, parallel-processing

My software processes received messages from different chats. I want to:

- Process them concurrently as much as system resources allow.
- But process messages from every single chat sequentially.

this is what I came up with:

```
public class PullUpdates
{
    private ConcurrentDictionary<string, ConcurrentQueue<Message>> chatsDictionary;
    private List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    // start pulling for ever
    public async void Start()
    {
        while (!stopPulling)
        {
            var messages = await api.GetMessages(); // it will return 100 messages
            foreach (var message in messages)
            {
                var queue = chatsDictionary.GetOrAdd(message.ChatId, x => new ConcurrentQueue<Message>());
                queue.Enqueue(message);
            }

            tasks.Add(Task.Run(() =>
            {
                // process chats in parallel
                Parallel.ForEach(chatsDictionary, async (dictionaryItem) =>
                {
                    // process messages of each chat sequentially
                    foreach (var message in dictionaryItem.Value)
                    {
                        await ParseMessageAsync(message);
                    }
                });
            }));

            // remove previous tasks that are completed now
            tasks.RemoveAll(x => x.IsCompleted);
        }

        // wait for remaining tasks before exiting
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }
}
```

It pulls a batch of messages, creates a new task to process chats in parallel, and parse messages sequentially and continues pulling again meanwhile.

---

It has two principal problems that I don't know how to solve them.

### How can I fix this:

1. It keeps adding new tasks without considering whether the system has the capacity or not.
2. It keeps pulling messages and adds them to the `chatsDictionary` while `Parallel.ForEach()`s working on the collection.

Comment: Why are you `await`ing for the tasks to finish *outside* the while loop?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Because I want they all finish before closing the app. And inside it I'm not awaiting because I want it keep pulling new batch of 100 messages. actually this is problem number 1.

Comment: So you want to keep adding work and at the same time control the amount of work that can be done at the same time? Why would you want to keep adding tasks if you know the system cannot handle more?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I don't know when the system can not handle more. I just want to get use of all the resources available, but when I should stop adding new tasks that's my problem here.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I read in the docs that `Parallel` determines how much work to perform concurrently based on the available resources, but I don't know how to use this.

Comment: Do you work online ( sourcing messages as they arrive via the API ), or do you plan to process digitally-siloed data ( the historically recorded set of all messages from past ) as fast as possible?

Comment: You should look in to using BlockingCollection, it is a wrapper for ConcurrentQueue letting you foreach over the collection easily using GetConsumingEnumerable()

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Sir, have a great day, take care of yourself and relax! That's exactly what I wanted https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/thread-safe/how-to-use-foreach-to-remove

Comment: Ok, once going into a `BlockingCollection`, `ConcurrentQueue`-attached process schedule, **the problem is definitely not a case of the true-`[PARALLEL]` system scheduling, but a "just"-`[CONCURRENT]` one**, as was revised already yesterday. Typing in any "parallel"-whatever, as a syntax keyword does nothing to re-formulate the actual problem, the less it can circumvent any actual blocking element in the code-execution flow down the road, Q.E.D. above. Anyway, enjoy the Xmas holiday time and all the best for the PF2018!